disable products without images via SQL
Any idea how to disable products without images via SQL ?
Magento ver. 2.4.3-p1
Thank you

We normally use this to detect if product has image
protected $_resource;
protected $_connection;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
    ...
) {
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    ...
}

public function getConnection()
{
    if (!$this->_connection) {
        $this->_connection = $this->_resource->getConnection('core_read');
    }
    return $this->_connection;
}

public function getResource()
{
    return $this->_resource;
}

protected function _hasImage($productId)
{
    $readConnection = $this->getResource()->getConnection('core_read');
    $query = $readConnection->select()
        ->from($this->getResource()->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity'))
        ->where('entity_id = ?', $productId);
    $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
    if (! empty($results)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

About status, you should find attribute ID in eav_attribute database table & then run your insert / update in catalog_product_entity_int database table

you can disable products without images in Magento 2 by using SQL. Here's a step-by-step plan:

Identify the entity_id of the products without images. In Magento, the catalog_product_entity table holds the entity_id of all products. The catalog_product_entity_varchar table holds the image data, where attribute_id for 'image' is usually 87 (this might differ in your setup, so please check).

Update the catalog_product_entity_int table to disable these products. The attribute_id for 'status' is usually 97 (this might differ in your setup, so please check). The status value for a disabled product is 2.


Here's the SQL query:
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int
SET value = 2
WHERE attribute_id = 97 AND entity_id IN (
    SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE entity_id NOT IN (
        SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id = 87 AND value != 'no_selection'
    )
);

Please replace 97 and 87 with the correct attribute_ids for 'status' and 'image' in your Magento setup. Also, please backup your database before running this query to prevent any data loss.
Remember, direct database manipulation is not recommended for Magento. It's better to create a script that uses Magento's API for such tasks.

Please try this will work :
UPDATE catalog_product_entity AS cpe
SET cpe.status = 2
WHERE cpe.entity_id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT cpeg.entity_id
    FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS cpeg
);


status is not present in catalog_product_entity database table
